# Angular 4 - CSS and app breaks in browsers IE and Edge

Tags: javascript, angular

I am getting this error in "EDGE" browser.

> Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Assignment to read-only properties
>   is not allowed in strict mode TypeError: Assignment to read-only
>   properties is not allowed in strict mode

The contents from the main page, i.e my dashboard are not populated. Application runs smoothly in browsers Chrome, Mozilla but breaks in IE and Edge.

How can i solve this issue?

Comment: Somewhere you put css style with js like: document.getElementById("xyz").style and change it to document.getElementById("text").style.cssText

Comment: Can you provide the code which is throwing this error?